# Signalr/hubs 404 with system.webServer/modules

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I've an old website which is using customized url rewriting like below:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="URLHandler" type="Lib.URLHandler" preCondition="" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Now when I add Signalr to this website, it gives me 404. Later I noticed that removing URLHandler module makes the Signalr working.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I cannot remove URLHandler as its managing lots of pages from a long time. So how can I make both Signalr and URLHandler work together?

Comment: Gives 404 on what resource? I assume `signalr/hubs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, in URLHandler I added a line that did the job for me.

```
void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower().Contains("signalr/hubs"))
           return;
      ..............
  }
```

I've also tried to work with generated proxy and it may work but its not as straight/helpful as chat hub like chatHub.server & chatHub.client isn't available and required to change the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

It this because it cannot find the generated proxy (`signalr/hubs`) because of changing url? If so, try using own proxy (code without generated proxy) i.e.:

Instead of:

```
var contosoChatHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;
```

Use:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();
var contosoChatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('contosoChatHub');
```

See examples without using generated proxy and read on here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy